# Using dotenv in cloud run

Tags: node.js, gcloud, dotenv

I have created a .env file in my local system while developing a project. If I upload my project along with .env file, will it work fine or do i have to assign env variables separately?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#yaml) it won't work like that.

You can set them in Console or provide with `--set-env-vars` flags during deployment from command line or set id Dockerfile with [`ENV` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#yaml).